# XAMPP: MySQL won't start, probably corrupt InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb, data-recovery

This is MySQL running on XAMPP on Windows 11.

I thought it was okay to shutdown MySQL from the XAMPP control panel, apparently not. Now it won't start again.

I've tried innodb_force_recovery. There are no backups, I just set it up the other day. There's a lot of fresh data in there I need.

Here are the logs:

```
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 20136596 between the checkpoint 20136596 and the end 20136448.
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-03-27 15:24:27 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 20136596 between the checkpoint 20136596 and the end 20136448.
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-03-27 15:24:35 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 20136596 between the checkpoint 20136596 and the end 20136448.
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-03-27 15:27:23 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I try innodb_force_recovery 3

```
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 20136596 between the checkpoint 20136596 and the end 20136448.
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-03-27 15:59:29 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I try innodb_force_recovery 6, the logs are happy but nothing happens, mysql is still not started.

```
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 6 !!!
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background log and ibuf IO write threads.
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery=6 skips redo log apply
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 0
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-27 15:59:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Any ideas?